# auto increment field gives error

Tags: php, mysql

How to make column autoincrement if  other fields are alresdy defined in mysql?
Error

SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `registration` ADD `rid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY ( `rid` )
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1068 - Multiple primary key defined
```

Here is ddl

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default     Extra   Action
rname   varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
rmobile     varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
first_name  varchar(37)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
last_name   varchar(27)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
date_of_birth   varchar(45)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
address     varchar(200)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
city    varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
state   varchar(200)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
postal_code     varchar(67)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
mobile_no   varchar(18)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
email_id    varchar(99)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
password    varchar(25)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
payment     bigint(50)          No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
pay     tinyint(1)          No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
status  tinyint(1)          No  None        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
dt  timestamp           Yes     NULL        Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index   Fulltext
```

Comment: show us ddl for table 'registration'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the error states, you already have a primary key in the table and you cannot have two columns as a primary key in a table. So make you new column UNIQUE and not a PK:

```
ALTER TABLE `registration` ADD `rid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE
```